# MySQL query within another query's for loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, for-loop, stored-procedures

I want to use the fetch results from different queries as an input in a mysql procedure. To do this, I wrote the following code:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","localhost") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($link)); 
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
    {
        printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }
$query_level1 = "select id,name...from table1; ";
    $query_level1 = "select id,address...from table2;";          
        if ($res_level1=mysqli_query($link,$query_level1))
        {
while ($row_l1 = mysqli_fetch_row($res_level1))
            {
                foreach($row_l1 as $key)
                {
                    $parent_l1 = explode(';',$key);
                    if ( 1 <count($parent_l1))
                    {
                        for ($i = 0;$i < count($parent_l1);$i++)
                        {
$res_level2=mysqli_query($link,$query_level2);
                            -----here fatch the result of $res_level2 into $child array with another for loop 
                            after this step call a procedure: 
                            if (!$link->query("call update_from_level1(" . $child[$k]  . "," . $parent_l1[$i] ")" )) 
                                    {
                                        echo "update_from_level1 : (" . $link->errno . ") ";
                                    }
                           }
                     }
                  }
               }
          }
```

If I fetch the result of `$query_level1`, it works properly; but when I fetch the result of `$query_level2`, it didn't work. Could you help me to figure out the problem?

Comment: You don't have any query string assigned to your `#query_level2`, as far as I can see from your code.

Comment: I didn't get the query_level2 in your code ,just change your second query variable name to level2 then check

Comment: I didn't write the Whole query,

Comment: $query_level1 = "SELECT id, name, description, type_id, url, icon_id, backend_id FROM map_node;"

Comment: $query_level2 = "SELECT id, name, description, org_id, business_criticity, move2production, finalclass 
    FROM functionalci ; "

Answer (score 1):

Mitstake

```
$query_level1 = "select id,name...from table1; ";
    $query_level1 = "select id,address...from table2;";
```

Comment: I have tested the two queries in mysql browser, and queries  are correct,  in the question I didn't write the Whole the query. I just want to figure out how to use second query in the for loop .

Comment: of course, both queries are correctly defined ; I want to figure out how to use second query in the for loo. thanks